# Sophos Safeguard detecting content of zip files being uploaded

Tags: physical, cloud-computing, content-security-policy

Is it possible to use Sophos safeguard to detect when computers in the network upload certain files online when they are compressed in a zip file? (or 7z or similar).

I've seen [it is possible with Sophos Safeguard to detect the upload of certain data to the cloud](https://www.sophos.com/en-us/support/knowledgebase/117053.aspx) (dropbox, google drive etc) But... what if the user compressed it? Would Sophos be able to inspect the compressed file to detect it?

Answer (score 1):

If the compressed file does not have a password, probably, assuming it can decompress it - there are size limitations in most products. If the archive is passworded, it is unlikely that any virus scanning software can inspect the contents.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Sorry, had sorting wrong and thought it was newest message :)

It depends on your license/installation/rules as you can have very different features wich you can not combine.

Attention: You should be aware that the solution you are trying to build will not be long "alive" as the  EOL is announced for next year.

Location based encryption can be configured that the files are always encrypted no matter where you move them. So nobody can read it if he has no certificate in Sophos Safeguard keychain